# Why did Riff Randell refer to The Ramones as brothers?

Tags: rock-n-roll-high-school

The 1979 movie [Rock 'N' Roll High School](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rock_%27n%27_Roll_High_School) features the punk band The Ramones.

The Ramones all have prominent cameo roles in the movie where they are all named and several of their actual albums are referenced.

Although the members of the band all have the same surname, they are **NOT** brothers, nor are they related in any way.  The surname [Ramone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramones) was adopted for entertainment purposes only.

There is a scene in the movie where Riff Randell claims that she would love to be the only sister in their family.

> Riff:  Kate, do you realize that they're all really brothers?  I mean,
>   imagine being the only sister in the Ramones family!

What was the purpose of including this in the movie?  Is there any evidence that the band requested that this be added to the movie?

Comment: Maybe it was meant as an inside joke? A nod to the fact that its a common misconception that they are brothers when they really aren't?

Comment: @sanpaco Well, I was one of those people who were duped into thinking that they were actually brothers for a while, just because of that line in the movie.  It's just bizarre, since several interviews I have seen with band members, they are adamant in emphasizing that they are NOT related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[As Tommy Ramone said](https://www.theguardian.com/music/2014/jul/12/tommy-ramone-last-original-member-ramones-dies-62):

> Tommy kept his links with the Ramones, co-producing further albums,
>   before starting an acoustic band called Uncle Monk with his partner
>   Claudia Tienan, playing bluegrass music. **It left him "baffled", he
>   said, that the original Ramones all fell out in later years. "We were
>   like brothers," he said.**

[This article](http://www.artslabormagazine.com/rip-the-ramones-band-of-brothers/) uses the title "Band of brothers" (partly in reference to a line from [the St. Crispin's Day speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St_Crispin%27s_Day_Speech)) and points out:

> No four guys from the same neighborhood were more different from each
>   other. And yet, when Jeffrey Hyman, John Cummings, Doug Colvin and
>   Tommy Erdelyi donned their uniform of black leather jackets and ripped
>   jeans and spit out 90-second songs, which would’ve run into each other
>   if not for the shout of “1-2-3-4!,” they became brothers: Joey,
>   Johnny, Dee Dee and Tommy. The Ramones! **Presenting themselves as much
>   a family as a band**, they were the group every outcast dreamed he was
>   in; thus many went out and started their own versions. No band has
>   ever moved more pawnshop guitars.

Also note this excerpt from Johnny Ramone's *Commando: The Autobiography of Johnny Ramone*:

[image: excerpt from Commando: The Autobiography of Johnny Ramone]

(I'll transcribe this later.)

Comment: Great answer!  As much of a Ramones fan that I am, I can't believe that I have not read any of their autobiographies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to be blood to be brothers. The point of the line is two fold. One is the common meaning,  that she could be one of them, an ad-hoc family. The other would be, she could be a band member, with the stage name of Ramones.